# javascript: get everything after certain characters from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get everything after certain characters in a string.

But I have no idea why with my, when I alert(); the result, there is a comma before the string!

Here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5LHFd/180/)

And this is my code:

```
var url = "mycool://?string=mysite.com/username_here80";
var urlsplit = url.split("mycool://?string=");

alert(urlsplit);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: String#split returns exactly an `Array` (yes, a real instance of `Array`, thus a way to get the latest element is by using the `last` getter), so `alert` stringifies this array of splits.

Comment: Do `url.split("=").pop()` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split separates the string into tokens separated by the delimiter. It always returns an array one longer than the number of tokens in the string. If there is one delimiter, there are two tokens—one to the left and one to the right. In your case, the token to the left is the empty string, so `split()` returns the array `["", "mysite.com/username_here80"]`. Try using

```
var urlsplit = url.split("mycool://?string=")[1]; // <= Note the [1]!
```

to retrieve the second string in the array (which is what you are interested in).

The reason you are getting a comma is that converting an array to a string (which is what `alert()` does) results in a comma-separated list of the array elements converted to strings.

Answer (score 4):

The [`split` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) of the `string` object returns an Array of elements, based on the splitter. In your case - the returned 2 elements:

```js
var url = "http://DOMAIN.com/username_here801";
var urlsplit = url.split("//");

console.log(urlsplit);
```

The comma you see is only the representation of the Array as string.

If you are looking for to get everything **after** a substring you better use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
var url = "http://DOMAIN.com/username_here801";
var splitter = '//'
var indexOf = url.indexOf(splitter);

console.log(url.slice(indexOf+splitter.length));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple replace..

```
var s = "mycool://?string=mysite.com/username_here80";
var ss = s.replace("mycool://?string=", "");
alert(ss);
```